# PHP: How to generate biased random numbers

Tags: php

I want to generate random numbers, but these numbers should be somewhat biased, 
so that numbers in certain ranges appear more frequently than others.

For example, to spread out a series of banner ad impressions in proportion to the number of impressions remaining for each ad campaign.

Comment: Heh - "I want random, but not that random..." :)

Comment: "Biased random numbers" There are so many possible jokes here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462219/xkcd-random-number

Comment: I know exactly how to generate a random biased number. `function getBiasedRandom() { return 12; }`. Its Biased, and Random!

Comment: Chacha101, everybody knows that 4 is a better random number than 12 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a random number between 0 and 1, and use it as the percentage of weight for any given banner. If the number is .3 or less, then a less popular (30% of the time) banner will show. If greater, a greater (70% of the time) banner will show.